# Sets satisfying certain condition

Tags: probability

I believe there must be sets satisfying the following condition, but I can not find them on top of my head.
$$
A,B\subset\Bbb{R}\quad\text{and}\quad P(A)=P(B)=1\quad\text{but}\quad P(A\cap B)<1
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  \begin{align*} P(A \cap B) = 1-P((A \cap B)^c) = 1-P(A^c \cup B^c)  \ge 1-(P(A^c) + P(B^c)) = 1.\end{align*}